# asymmetric file system authentication

Tags: authentication, asymmetric, file-system

Here is how `integritysetup` from the `cryptsetup` package in Linux works. A user provides an authentication key to the OS when reading or writing data to a file system. When reading, the OS only returns a data block if it was written with the same key as it is being read. Hence the same key is used when writing and reading.

Authentication for email allows different keys for writing and reading. The secret key from a key pair is used for writing (signing), and the public key from the same key pair is used for reading (verifying a signature). I'm imagining that a key pair may be used for file system authentication too.

Such an authentication may be useful for the OS file system on a multi-user computer. Only the system administrator has the secret key, so only the system administrator can install or update the software on the computer. Every user has the public key, so every user can verify that the software isn't a trojan. The system administrator is not needed to start the computer.

AFAIK, Linux doesn't provide such authentication. I wonder does any OS provides such authentication? Full-disk authentication is okay too.

Comment: If only the system admin has the secret key, how will you add/edit files in the system?

Comment: @Limit A system administrator will edit the file system. Obviously, this file system is not required to contain all data. This file system is intended for executable files and configuration.

Comment: I am not sure about the practicality of this. Many applications write logs to the log files. Where will that log file be? Will the apps be running in admin mode to execute this?

Comment: @Limit Good catch. Logs may be stored: (0) in memory only since they are not critical for software functioning, (1) on an unprotected medium if they don't need to be secure (for example, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is readable by every computer user anyway), (c) on a medium writable by every computer user, so at least we restricted the access to logs.